# iOS: Instrument's timer profile Symbol Name

Tags: ios5, profiling, instruments, symbols

Could someone please tell me what are the settings to get the Symbol names in strings rather than hex codes in attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved. I had to set `Scheme` for `Profile` to `Debug` to see symbol names. It was set to `Release` before!